# Ajax Webapi Post request for crossdomain in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access a WebAPI (in the same server but different IP). It works like a charm in IE 10 . But in IE 8 it goes worse. I have included $.support.cors=true and also included the jQuery.XDomainRequest.js which I got from 
https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-DomainRequest/blob/master/jQuery.XDomainRequest.js

For the GET request it is working, but for the post its throwing out error. I learned that for POSt content type should be text/plain. 
I tried to send my data as a plain text, probably the server is not parsing it properly.
I also tried jsonp as well, but didn't work
I am putting down my webapi call . Please suggest on how can I get this working. Thanks a lot .

```
function Authenticate() {

 var UserInfoRequest = {
        Email: $("#txtEmail").val(), SubDomain: subDomainName
    };


    //UserInfoRequest ="Email="+$("#txtEmail").val()+"&SubDomain="+subDomainName;


    $.ajax({
        url: defaultAPIurl + "Login/UserExistOrDualRole"  ,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
    data:   UserInfoRequest ,

        success: function (data) {


            //do something 

        },
        error: function (data) {
            Showerror();
            return;

        }
    });





    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which version of _jQuery_ are you using?

Comment: I am using Jquery V1.9

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WEB API support CROS need extra library. Check this post:[CORS support for ASP.NET Web API](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs)

Modified your project as this post written,it's will be working.

tips:The two library at their [NightBuild Nuget server](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds) when I used it.